# get data from firebase children

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have two custom cells in one table view.

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // Configure the cell...
     if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Main", for: indexPath) as! PostTableViewCell

        //Configure the cell

        cell.PostView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        cell.PostView.layer.masksToBounds = false
        cell.PostView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.4).cgColor
        cell.PostView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
        cell.PostView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.9

        let post = Comments[indexPath.row] as! [String: AnyObject]
        let commentname = post["author"] as? String
        sendAuthor = post["author"] as? String
        cell.CommentersName.setTitle(commentname, for: .normal)

        if let seconds = post["pub_time"] as? Double {
            let timeStampDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: seconds/1000)
            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM d, yyyy"
            let formating = timeStampDate as Date


            cell.CommentTime.text = dateFormatter.string(from: formating)


        }

        cell.comment.text = post["content"] as? String


         textViewDidChange(cell.comment)

        cell.comment.frame.size.width = 344
        cell.comment.sizeToFit()
        cell.comment.clipsToBounds = true

        cell.REply.frame.origin.y = cell.comment.frame.maxY + 10
        cell.PostView.frame.size.height =  cell.comment.frame.maxY + 50
        TableView.rowHeight = cell.PostView.frame.size.height + 20


        cell.LikesNumber.text = post["num_likes"] as? String


        replyId = post["id"] as? String

        cell.checkfornightmode()

        return cell
       }
          else{

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Reply", for: indexPath) as! RepliesTableViewCell



            cell.ReplyCustomCell.layer.cornerRadius = 5
            cell.ReplyCustomCell.layer.masksToBounds = false
            cell.ReplyCustomCell.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.4).cgColor
            cell.ReplyCustomCell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
            cell.ReplyCustomCell.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.9

        let post = Comments[indexPath.row] as! [String: AnyObject]

        let posttest = post["id"] as? String

        let replyRef = Database.database().reference().child("main").child("posts").child(postID!).child("comments").child(posttest!).child("comments")


        replyRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot:DataSnapshot) in

            if let postsDictionary = snapshot .value as? [String: AnyObject] {



                for testingkey in postsDictionary.keys {


                    Database.database().reference().child("main").child("posts").child(self.postID!).child("comments").child(posttest!).child("comments").child(testingkey).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

                        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

                        let content : String? = value?["content"] as? String ?? ""

                       cell.ReplyText.text = content!

                    })
                }



            }

        })


        TableView.rowHeight = 150.0


            return cell
       }
    }
```

The first cell with the identifier main is supposed to print out all the intial comments for a certain post. The second cell with the identifier is supposed to print out the comments to main comments. Based on this code, I am only getting the last comment of the main post and the last comment to the main posts.

This is what the json looks like 
[image]
[image]

Comment: First clean up your code with the instructions below it will resolve the issue for you. You are making calls again and again in a reusable cell that's creating an issue here.

Answer (score 0):

1. First thing is to separate the firebase call into a separate function and in that function populate a dictionary with posts as key and comments as value

for example like this

```
var postComments: [String: [String]] = [:] // post as key and string array as comments
```

2. In firebase database call populate this with snapshot.

After the data call but within the firebase Database call back use this function to reload data

```
DispatchQueue.main.async{
  tableView.reloadData() 
}
```

3. Set the cell with postComments array.